# Replace a word in a String by indexing without "string replace function" -python

Tags: python, string, indexing, replace

Is there a way to replace a word within a string without using a "string replace function," e.g., string.replace(string,word,replacement).

```
[out] = forecast('This snowy weather is so cold.','cold','awesome')
out => 'This snowy weather is so awesome.
```

Here the word cold is replaced with awesome.

This is from my MATLAB homework which I am trying to do in python. When doing this in MATLAB we were not allowed to us strrep().

In MATLAB, I can use strfind to find the index and work from there. However, I noticed that there is a big difference between lists and strings. Strings are immutable in python and will likely have to import some module to change it to a different data type so I can work with it like how I want to without using a string replace function.

Answer (score 0):

just for fun :)

```
st = 'This snowy weather is so cold .'.split()
given_word = 'awesome'
for i, word in enumerate(st):
    if word == 'cold':
        st.pop(i)                                                                                                                                                                 
        st[i - 1] = given_word
        break # break if we found first word

print(' '.join(st))
```

Comment: Shoot I was going to add that I want to refrain from using iteration for this assignement since we didnt learn iteration at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another answer that might be closer to the solution you described using MATLAB:

```
st = 'This snow weather is so cold.'
given_word = 'awesome'
word_to_replace = 'cold'
n = len(word_to_replace)

index_of_word_to_replace = st.find(word_to_replace)

print st[:index_of_word_to_replace]+given_word+st[index_of_word_to_replace+n:]
```

Comment: Thank you. I should have been able to come up with this solution since this is remarkably similar to the MATLAB solution. Is there a hint to finding the solutions to these programs. I seem to struggle a lot in this area and over think it a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your string into a list object, find the index of the word you want to replace and then replace the word.

```
sentence = "This snowy weather is so cold"

# Split the sentence into a list of the words
words = sentence.split(" ")

# Get the index of the word you want to replace
word_to_replace_index = words.index("cold")

# Replace the target word with the new word based on the index
words[word_to_replace_index] = "awesome"

# Generate a new sentence
new_sentence = ' '.join(words)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Regex and a list comprehension.

```
import re
def strReplace(sentence, toReplace, toReplaceWith):
    return " ".join([re.sub(toReplace, toReplaceWith, i) if re.search(toReplace, i) else i for i in sentence.split()])

print(strReplace('This snowy weather is so cold.', 'cold', 'awesome'))
```

**Output:**

```
This snowy weather is so awesome.
```